# IBM Watson Conversation API returning parent node always, not inserting into child node

Tags: java, watson-conversation

I am trying to make a conversation in java using IBM Watson Conversation API .
I am also passing

> context

in message request.Still its returning same.

```
static Map<String, Object> context = new HashMap<String, Object>();
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "10.xx.xx.xx");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "80");
    ConversationService service = new ConversationService(ConversationService.VERSION_DATE_2016_07_11);
    service.setUsernameAndPassword("xxxxxx", "xxxxxx");

    MessageRequest newMessage = new MessageRequest.Builder().inputText("galaxy light").context(context).build();
    MessageResponse response = service.message("xxxxx", newMessage).execute();
        context = response.getContext();

    System.out.println(context);
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

I am  saving the context and passing again.

```
"output": {
    "log_messages": [],
    "text": [
      "i did not understand you may say can you add hot chocolate"
    ],
    "nodes_visited": [
      "node_2_1487682572904"
    ]
  },
  "input": {
    "text": "galaxy light"
  }
```

what else i can do in this?

Comment: System.out.println(context) show something?

Answer (score 1):

Your first call is always going to have a blank context going in. Your sample code is the initial call.

If you make further calls, then you send back the returning context from before to maintain state.

However your issue looks like it might be different. In this case, at a guess you are hitting the `anything_else` node. Intents will not be matched if the confidence <0.2 . So you need to check your `intents[]` part of the JSON to see if the system needs more training.

Quick way to do this is to put the following in your output.

```
<? intents ?>
```

I also recommend to switch on `alternate_intents` while you are testing.

Other then that, there is not much to go on above. I would recommend posting the full JSON response.